# create random top , right for each div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create random top , right for each div

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.cube {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:25px;
    position:absolute;
}
</style>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    var Wh = window.innerHeight;
    var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * Wh);
    $('.cube').each(function() {
          $(this).css({"right":number+"px","top":number+"px"});
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="cube"></div>
<div class="cube"></div>
<div class="cube"></div>
<div class="cube"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

i don't know why each function not working here !
i see only one div changed , how can i fix this ?

Comment: where div closed tags ? O_o

Comment: id's are meant to be unique use class & getElementsByClassName(); & inside the random function subtract the div height.. 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * Wh)-50 if you want to keep them inside the window.

Comment: Is this how you want displayed http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/aZ4WV/ ?

Answer (score 4):

Close your `<div>`s and change ID to classes:

```
<div class="cube"></div>
<div class="cube"></div>
<div class="cube"></div>
<div class="cube"></div>
```

Now, I think you want to apply a different position to each cube, so alter your code like this:

```
$(function () {       
    var Wh = window.innerHeight;
    $('.cube').each(function() {
         var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * Wh);
        $(this).css({"right":number+"px","top":number+"px"});
    });
});
```

The `$(this)` part is important, as it applies the positioning to a single DOM element, and not all elements with a class of `.cube`.

*UPDATE*

Also move your random number generator into the `each` function, so that a new number will be generated each time.

Comment: FYI: `$('#cube').each` doesn't do what you think it does here.

Comment: I just saw the ID, updated for classes. `each` traverses each item selected by jQuery, and this will apply a different position for each `.cube` element, which I believe is the OP's intention.

Answer (score 0):

Booo, you cant do this: `<div id="cube"><div id="cube"><div id="cube">`

Id must be unique at ALL times. You need to use class. Like so: `<div class="cube">`

In JavaScript reference it by `$('.cube')`

Also close those divs man.

**Your JavaScript should look like:**

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var wh = window.innerHeight;


    $('.cube').each(function() {
        var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * wh);
        //$(this) refers to the current object in the 'each' iteration
        $(this).css({"right":number+"px","top":number+"px"});
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i edited document and updated my post , but it still not working :)

Comment: Updated code, Chris' suggestion was correct. Random number generation needs to be inside loop so that it is regenerated on each iteration. This should work, check browser console for errors.